# python - pyinstaller hidden_import exe file then subprocess Popen the exe file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, popen

is it possible in the .spec file to include as hidden_import an exe file, and then in then main py script use a command subprocess.Popen to run it?

I am getting an error like:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "running_example.py", line 40, in <module>
    s = shout.Shout()
  File "shout.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.p1 = Popen([resource_path0("msys_shout.exe")], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,shell=False, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1, close_fds=ON_POSIX)
  File "subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

where resource_path0 function is:

```py
def resource_path0(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path = getattr(
        sys,
        '_MEIPASS',
        os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

the .spec file is:

```py
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['running_example.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=["msys_shout.*","shout.*","*.mp3"],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='running_example',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

Comment: No, it's for hidden imports. What you're trying to do is add a data file, which you can do. Have a look at the manual here https://pyinstaller.org/en/v4.2/spec-files.html#adding-data-files

Comment: @Grismar yes using `data` instead of `hidden_import` solves the issue. One question: Is `resource_path0` function necessary?

Answer (score 0):

As @Grismar suggested using this spec file:

```py
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['running_example.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[ ('msys_shout.exe', '.'), ('*.mp3','.') ],
    hiddenimports=["shout"],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='running_example',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

and then running: `python -m PyInstaller running_example.spec` solves the problem.

Thanks Grismar.

So to summarize: when a .py script is imported use `hidden_import`, for other situations like txt files, mp3 files, exe files whose the paths are referenced inside the python script use `datas` in the spec file.